# how to compare two table MD5 values to identify virus in java

Tags: java, ms-access

There are two databases, each having one table. I am trying to compare the MD5 values.

```
for (int i=0;rs.next();i++ )
{
    String s=rs.getString(2);
    System.out.println(i+"   "+s);
    for (int j=1;rs1.next() ;j++ )
    {
        String s1=rs1.getString(1);
        //int t =s.equals(s1);
        if (s.equals(s1))
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
        }
        System.out.println(j+"  "+s1);
    }
    }
    con.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem? Seems like you are doing string comparisons for each string that you retrieve from DB `A` to all strings you retrieve from DB `B`.

Comment: What's your exact question/problem?

Comment: could not able to get result from comarison

Comment: how to compare these values

Answer (score 0):

the solution below shows you how to calculate MD5 on the fly, which works for huge data. The example was written for a text file, but of course you could use any other inputstream.

if you need to pipe from a writer (when you iterate the resultset) to a reader, you'll probably need some piped stream (see http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2010/11/using-a-pipedinputstream-and-pipedoutputstream/) but if that's not the case, you can just dump your data to some file and then read from it.

now, if you want to compare two tables, you must ensure first that both will generate the same strings, which means that float values, dates, etc must follow the same formats. And they must sort rows in the same way for both (sometimes, different databases don't sort data the same way, for example, strings that start with special chars)

but if they are the same type, everything is easier, of course.

well, here's the MD5 stuff. Good luck.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;


public class CheckSumFileTest 
{

    private File buildChecksumFile(File fileToCheck, String filePrefix, String checksumAlgorithm) throws Exception
    {
        String checksum = null;
        File checksumFile = null;
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        try {
            checksumFile = new File(tempDir, filePrefix+"."+ checksumAlgorithm.toLowerCase());
            checksumFile.createNewFile();
            checksumFile.deleteOnExit();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        }
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            checksum = checkSum(fileToCheck,checksumAlgorithm);
            fw = new FileWriter(checksumFile);
            fw.write(checksum);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(fw !=null)
                fw.close();
        }

        return checksumFile;
    }

    private static String checkSum(File file, String checksumAlgorithm) throws Exception
    {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(checksumAlgorithm);

        InputStream input = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try{
            input = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            do {
                int read = input.read(buffer);
                if(read <= 0)
                    break;
                digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
            } while(true);
            byte[] sum = digest.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((sum[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

        }catch(IOException io)
        {

        }finally{
            if(input != null)
                input.close();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String checkSumInStream(InputStream stream, String checksumAlgorithm) throws Exception
    {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(checksumAlgorithm);

        InputStream input = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try{
            input = stream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            do {
                int read = input.read(buffer);
                if(read <= 0)
                    break;
                digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
            } while(true);
            byte[] sum = digest.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((sum[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

        }catch(IOException io)
        {

        }finally{
            if(input != null)
                input.close();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private boolean checkIntegrity(String targetFileName, String checksumFileName, String checksumAlgorithm) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        InputStreamReader ipsr = null;
        File checksumFile = null;
        String checksumString="";
        File targetFile = new File(targetFileName);
        try{
            checksumFile = new File(checksumFileName);
            stream = new FileInputStream(checksumFile);
            ipsr = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);

            //In checksum file : only one line to read
            checksumString = br.readLine();

        }finally
        {
            if(br != null)
                br.close();
            if(ipsr != null)
                ipsr.close();
            if(stream != null)
                stream.close();
        }


        if(checksumString.equals(checkSum(targetFile,checksumAlgorithm)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "Amine";
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        //step1
        try {
            System.out.println(checkSumInStream(stream,"MD5"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //step2
        File file = new File("c:/test.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(str);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(checkSum(file, "MD5"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```